# Как сделать отображение базы данных с phpmyadmin в активити?

Tags: php, java, android-studio

Я понимаю то что оно создается с помощью recyclerview или ListView, но как? Помогите мне пожалуйста с кодом!

Comment: так код в студию. как сами пытаетесь. вам нужно просто подконектиться к базе удаленно делать запросы и выводить данные.

Comment: Разбейте задачу на части. Разберитесь как достать данные приложением с удалённой БД, разберитесь как отобразить набор данных/строк в recyclerview. После - соедините и получите результат.

Comment: phpmyadmin - это всего лишь вебморда для MySQL стоящего на сервере и насколько я помню у него нет внешнего API. Поэтому возникает вопрос что именно вам нужно(отобразить phpmyadmin или БД из MySQL). Отобразить phpmyadmin в андроид приложении можно только с помощью WebView. А вот с БД немного другое дело - Можно подключиться напрямую к MySQL, но тут есть минусы. т.к. во-первых на сервере чаще всего закрыты порты для прямого подключения к MySQL извне и они доступны только для локального пользователя. Во-вторых - вы будете тратить подключения к MySQL

Comment: Подключения к MySQL имеют свойство быстро заканчиваться если их корректно не закрывать

Comment: Один из самых частых способов - это проектирование и разработка сервиса(REST-сервиса например) для отдачи данных из MySQL и работа в android приложении уже с сервисом.Тут вы сможете достучаться до базы на сервере, в котором закрыты порты для доступа к ней извне. Веб-сервис может хранить пул подключений к MySQL и экономить их. Но при этом вы не сможете работать с произвольной базой без этого самого сервиса...

Comment: и в зависимости от того что у вас есть и что вам нужно вы можете выбрать тот или иной вариант